# Which DOM event to attach eventHandler to for this specific use case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to replace a string on my site with some other text. But the component of the page that the string is part of seems to load later than the page itself. What DOM event should I attach my eventHandler to?

I have the following code block:

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("woocommerce-privacy-policy-text")[0].innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

This should replace the text "Vos donnÃ©es personnelles..." on https://woocommerce-549279-2833830.cloudwaysapps.com/checkout?add-to-cart=14.

But if a site visitor doesn't need to scroll down, this doesn't work...
For example: refresh that page when you have the text (to the right above the place order button) already on screen, so that you don't need to scroll...

What is the best DOM event to attach the eventListener to? I would like it to change the text immediately upon page loading.

Comment: Did you try encapsulate your above code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` to add the event listener after the page being ready and loaded?

Comment: If this is your site you should have control on how and when this component loads. Can you show that to us? (And actually you should even have control on its content to begin with, so there shouldn't be a need to wait or change later, directly set the correct value)

Comment: @YasserMohsen, if I wrap it inside the code you suggest, I get an error in the console: "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function".

Comment: @Kaiido, My site is a WordPress site that uses the WooCommerce plugin. The WooCommerce plugin renders this component. I could change the plugin in the back, but that would be problematic for when there's an update of the plugin.

Comment: @Marty, surely it is not recommended to change the plugin code locally. If necessary, you can support the plugin by adding your changes and do a pull request if available so that everyone can use later

Comment: @Marty, if $ is not working properly, this means that JQuery is not loaded in your page. The other way is to check if your page is completely loaded through Vanilla Javascript using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {})`

Comment: Still, could you please link to said extension exactly, and show the options you've used. They probably have a documentation, maybe they have an option to set this text (maybe just a localization file), maybe they already fire a custom event you can hook on...

Comment: The plugin of concern is the core plugin of WooCommerce: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you not hide it with CSS? Maybe use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect DOM changes as they occur.

Let's have a test:

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector("#order_review");
setTimeout(function() {
  $(wrapper).append(`<div id="payment" class="woocommerce-checkout-payment">
    <ul class="wc_payment_methods payment_methods methods">
      <li class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--info woocommerce-info">Sorry, it seems that there are no available payment methods for your state. Please contact us if you require assistance or wish to make alternate arrangements.</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="form-row place-order">
      <noscript>
            Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled, please ensure you click the <em>Update Totals</em> button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount stated above if you fail to do so.          <br/><button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals" value="Update totals">Update totals</button>
        </noscript>

      <div class="woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper">
        <div class="woocommerce-privacy-policy-text">
          <p>Vos donnÃ©es personnelles seront utilisÃ©es pour le traitement de votre commande, vous accompagner au cours de votre visite du site web, et pour dâ€™autres raisons dÃ©crites dans notre <a href="https://woocommerce-549279-2833830.cloudwaysapps.com/privacy-policy"
              class="woocommerce-privacy-policy-link" target="_blank">privacy policy</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>

      <input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" name="woocommerce-process-checkout-nonce" value="08ad43aa7a"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/?wc-ajax=update_order_review"> </div>
  </div>

</div>`);
}, 1000);

// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = wrapper;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  console.log("something changed");
  $(".woocommerce-privacy-policy-text")[0].innerHTML = "Hello world!"

  // Later, you can stop observing
  observer.disconnect();
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
  <table class="shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="product-name">Product</th>
        <th class="product-total">Subtotal</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="cart_item">
        <td class="product-name">
          Product1&nbsp; <strong class="product-quantity">×&nbsp;10</strong> </td>
        <td class="product-total">
          <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,110.00</bdi>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>

      <tr class="cart-subtotal">
        <th>Subtotal</th>
        <td><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,110.00</bdi>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>



      <tr class="order-total">
        <th>Total</th>
        <td><strong><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>1,110.00</bdi></span></strong> </td>
      </tr>


    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I get 2 errors if I add this as a code snippet to my Wordpress site: `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')`. But also, you still need to scroll before it replaces the text. So if you reload the page with the text already on screen (and thus no need to scroll), the old text is displayed.

Comment: So you need to observe a "higher" parent element than `.woocommerce-terms-and-conditions-wrapper`