# Hide list item using data attribute when specific text is present on the page with JS

Tags: javascript, if-statement, string-search

This is trying to hide a checkout payment option from appearing when specific items are in cart (shown on the same page). If the text "BULK" appears in the cart/page to hide a list option based on its data attribute? I've tried learning js and the last 2 hours of watching a course, I understand more but this still seems more advanced than what I can do right now. Would a boolean argument using string.search and insert div.style.display "none"?

Cart example to search for text:
`<h4 class="product-title optimizedCheckout-contentPrimary" data-test="cart-item-product-title">BULK Powder 50 lbs.</h4>`

Payment option:
`<li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item" data-test="accordion-item_paypalcommerce">`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a reference to the item (or items - same idea only in a loop) - read the text of the element. Using `indexOf` sounds reasonable to find a string inside another. And if all is well then just set `display:none` to the right payment option.

The javascript is basic, but you should also learn some about css selectors should you want to "select" the target elements using a different strategy.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".product-title");
var bool = elem.innerText.indexOf('BULK')>=0
if (bool) {
  var li = document.querySelector("li[data-test='accordion-item_paypalcommerce']");
  li.style.display = 'none'
}
```

```html
<h4 class="product-title optimizedCheckout-contentPrimary" data-test="cart-item-product-title">BULK Powder 50 lbs.</h4>

Payment options:
<li class="form-checklist-item optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item" data-test="accordion-item_paypalcommerce">Cash</li>
<li class="form-checklist-item" data-test="accordion-item_paypalcommerce">Credit</li>
```

Comment: So the li.optimizedCheckout-form-checklist-item class is utilized for all the items in the list, is there a way to specify the data-test attribute? This attribute is unique for each item, I'm just not sure how have that parameter. Would the below function correctly?

`var elem = document.querySelector(".product-title");
var bool = elem.innerText.indexOf('BULK')>=0
if (bool) {
  var li = document.querySelector('[data-test="accordion-item_paypalcommerce"]');
  
  li.style.display = 'none'
}`

Comment: I tried my little variation with the data Id, however, in the console throws an error: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')"

Comment: That's reading 'innerText' of the element that supposed to have the class "product-title". Does it appear on the page source?  Does the script execute too early before it is rendered?

Comment: The script appears on page source, however the .product-title nor "BULK" appear. This is happening on a bigcommerce one-step checkout.

Comment: So in this case you would need to add a MutationObserver to detect changes in the dom element that contains the soon to be title. That would trigger a callback so you would know when to search for the title. See other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73509280/3807365) of mine on the subject